# Git fetch and reset not working as expected

Tags: git

A teammate made some fixes in master, and I'm trying to rebase my branch (feature/me/foo, which has three commits after 0f0) onto it.

If I just rebase, the three-way merge clobbers all my changes (in the three files he’s changed). So I found this sweet command:

```
$ git rebase -s ours master
```

Except it's not at all what I want:

```
$ git log

commit 20dee42d3e7c06f94618d4e39e84bc07ad2aff9f 
Author: [him] 
Date:   Fri Jun 10 14:09:35 2016 -0700

commit 0f0dac94a0094817a3191f699b1b438ec89aaec2 
Author: [me] 
Date:   Fri Jun 10 09:14:47 2016 -0700
```

My last three commits (after 0f0) disappeared and are replaced by his. No problem. I'll just revert:

```
( feature/me/foo ) 11:16:35 > git fetch --all 
Fetching origin no slots

( feature/me/foo ) 11:16:45 > git reset --hard 
feature/me/foo HEAD is now at 20dee42 + minor updates:
```

...except I'm still pointing at his changes, and not the latest from my branch. If I nuke and clone, I get back to the correct state on my branch.

What’s the proper way to “hard reset” my branch to the remote state?

Answer (score 0):

To hard reset your branch with the remote:

```
git checkout another-branch
git checkout /remotes/origin/master
git branch -D master
git checkout master
```

The idea is to move to another branch, move to the remote refence, remove master, and finally crear a new master branch linked to the remote branch.

This is not a good practice, but will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to find the SHA of your desire commit in reflog and reset to it.

```
git reflog # find SHA or short name, for example 0f0dac94
git reset --hard 0f0dac94
```

Answer (score 0):

If your branch has an upstream set up, then simply

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

(`@{u}` or `@{upstream}` means "upstream of current branch").

Otherwise, use remote branch name:

```
git reset --hard origin/branch_name
```

Comment: I tried the version with branch name (didn't work), but not with upstream. Shouldn't the remote branch name have worked either way?

Comment: Are you sure you used the _remote_ branch name? And when you say it didn't work, what exactly does this mean?

Comment: Ah! I cannot be sure that I did try the remote branch name. "Didn't work" in that my log still showed that I was at his commit.